# How can I get custom sails generators to work?

Tags: reactjs, sails.js, generator

I am currently working on trying to build a website that has a React frontend and Sails backend. I found that I can use generators to override the core Sails generator that is currently configured to work with Vue, and I found this generator online: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-generate-reactjs

However, when I follow the steps exactly, the newly created web app is still implemented in Vue. I'm not sure if I'm missing anything or if something is outdated, but any help would be greatly appreciated!